# Requesting Client Certificate with Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, client-certificates, mutual-authentication

I'm trying to retrieve from the client browser a client certificate to authenticate the user. I know i can create a folder with the same name as the controller and, with IIS, set its SSL settings to require a client certificate. In fact, I've tried this and it worked, but i can't take this approach because there are other actions inside the controller that don't need to ask the user for a client certificate. Also i need to ask the client certificate in different controllers.

So, do you know a clean (if possible) way to prompt the user to select a client certificate?

Answer (score 0):

there are several pre-requisites.

```
Trusted CA root certificate.
Server Certificate from a trusted CA.
Client Certificate from a trusted CA.
```

you can see this article to set initial configuration on IIS: [How to configure IIS client certificate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2014/02/13/how-to-configure-iis-client-certificate-mapping-authentication-for-iis7.aspx)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

try to use this attribute [RequireHttps] to action/controller if you need to defend it by ssl certificate.